# How do immutable v. mutable arrays work, with respect to memory?

Tags: arrays, immutability, mutability

Specifically, why aren't all arrays in languages mutable - what are the reasons a language would or wouldn't have them (advantages and disadvantages)?

Comment: Some languages can't implement or guarantee the implementation of strictly mutable arrays.  In many terms it may not make sense; you'd have to know "the world" before you were able to start populating the array, whereas typically it's the other way around - you populate the array as you learn "the world".

Comment: One advantage of an immutable array is that since you (and/or the compiler) know for a fact that it will never change, you can do things like allow multiple threads to read from it simultaneously without requiring any synchronization, and represent multiple "copies" of the array via pointers/references to a single global copy.  With an array that might change, these optimizations would be unsafe to do.

Answer (score 1):

Under the covers, every byte in memory is "mutable".  An array (in, say, Objective-C) is immutable because some sort of flag or type indicator in it says it's immmutable.

There are basically 3 reasons for having an object be immutable:

1. Security/robustness -- An object can be passed to an interface with confidence on both sides that the object will not be dynamically modified.  Modification after an object is passed could, eg, allow a baddie to change a parameter after the parameter has been validity checked.
2. Ease of implementation -- It may be easier to build an object with a fixed structure and contents than one that can be modified.
3. Concurrency -- If an object can be dynamically modified then it is necessary to consider what happens in the case of concurrent modification in two threads or when modified in one thread while being accessed in another.  Such concurrent modification can cause program malfunctions or cause the object itself to behave improperly.

Comment: Concurrency still needs to be considered with immutable data objects. It's just that instead of writing to an object, you replace it. Two threads can still derive a new version from the same old version if you're not locking.

Comment: @JanDvorak - When you replace an object, you use a new pointer/reference.  Any concurrency issues (other than low-level cache synchronization) are around the management of the pointer, not the internals of the object.